# UITableViewStyleGrouped is not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

```
OptionsVC.h    
   @interface OptionsVC : UITableViewController

    .
    .
    .

OtherController.m
    OptionsVC *options = [[OptionsVC alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
```

I dont know why but this code is not working, I am getting plain style. How to fix it?

Comment: please provide more code

Comment: Have you added the UITableView in xib? If so, you can set the property style to Grouped there itself

Comment: Hi, thats why I included @interface OptionsVC : UITableViewController means its a UITableViewController subclass :)

Comment: Sorry for not noticing .... But then, did you set the property style to Grouped in xib?

Comment: thanks a lot it worked by setting grouped in xib, post it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the property **Style** to **Grouped** in your **xib file**

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following

```
 OptionsVC *options = [[OptionsVC alloc]init];
 options.tableView.style = UITableViewStyleGrouped;
```

Hope it will work.....